# Parse Data in XML Document to Excel Worksheet

Tags: xml, vba, excel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xa:MeContext id="ABCe0552553">
  <xa:Data id="ABCe05525531" />
  <xa:Data id="1" />
  <CustID>Cust1234</CustID>
  <Name>Smith</Name>
  <City>New York</City>
  <Orders>
    <order Orderid="101">
      <Product>MP3 Player</Product>
    </order>
    <order Orderid="102">
      <Product>Radio</Product>
    </order>
  </Orders>
</xa:MeContext>
```

This well formed XML document feeds to Excel 2007 using MS VBA code.  I was successful 
with using `DOMDocument` and `IXMLDOMElement` to import the Name, City, and Product.
However, the `xa:MeContext id`, `vsData1 id`, `VsData2 id`, `CustID`, and `order Orderid` number won't export to Excel sheet.

Each Excel row has the following headers with data filled from XML document:

```
MeContextID--vsData1--VsData2--CustID--Name--City--OrderID--Product--OrderID--Product
```

Comment: The XML is not well formed.  Both `<Data>` nodes have no closing tag.  Is it supposed to be: `<xa:Data id="ABCe05525531" />`?

Comment: Also, I assume the namespace on `<MeContext>` is a typo, but the opening tag has `xa` and the closing tag has `xn`

Comment: You are correct.  I removed the end tags for clarity.  Please let me know if you can help.

Comment: Based on your comment, I have edited your XML so it is well formed.  I am slightly confused by the fact that you removed the end tags for clarity, so if I put the end tags in the wrong spot, please edit the question yourself as it should be.

Comment: Next step is to ask you to show some code... how are you reading the data into Excel.

Comment: brtn = xml_doc.Load("C:\cust.xml") 'xml_doc exiting reference

intr = 2
If brtn Then
   With Sheets("Sheet2")   
       For Each onode In xml_doc.SelectNodes("//xa:MeContext")
           .Cells(intr, 1) = onode.getAttribute("xa:Data")
           .Cells(intr, 2) = onode.getAttribute("xa:Data")
           .Cells(intr, 3) = onode.Text
           
           intr = intr + 1
       Next
   End With
Else
    MsgBox "Unable to open XML File"
End If

Comment: @user1714065 - can you put your code in the original question. That will make it much easier to read than it is in your comment here. Thanks, PDW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are two methods to output the fields you need. Note, that the XML you have posted does not contain the header definitions for namespace "xa:" so is not fully formed XML. I've removed them in the example so MSXML2.DOMDocument doesn't throw a parse error.

```
Option Explicit
Sub XMLMethod()
Dim XMLString As String
Dim XMLDoc As Object
Dim boolValue As Boolean
Dim xmlDocEl As Object
Dim xMeContext As Object
Dim xChild As Object
Dim xorder As Object


    XMLString = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

    'Remove xa: in this example
    'reason : "Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'xa'."
    'Shouldn't need to do this if full XML is well formed containing correct namespace
    XMLString = Replace(XMLString, "xa:", vbNullString)

    Set XMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    'XMLDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xa:"

        'XMLDoc.Load = "C:\Users\ooo\Desktop\test.xml" 'load from file
    boolValue = XMLDoc.LoadXML(XMLString)  'load from string

    Set xmlDocEl = XMLDoc.DocumentElement
    Set xMeContext = xmlDocEl.SelectSingleNode("//MeContext")
        Debug.Print Split(xMeContext.XML, """")(1)
    For Each xChild In xmlDocEl.ChildNodes

        If xChild.NodeName = "Orders" Then
            For Each xorder In xChild.ChildNodes
                Debug.Print Split(xorder.XML, """")(1)
                Debug.Print xorder.Text
            Next xorder

        ElseIf xChild.Text = "" Then
            Debug.Print Split(xChild.XML, """")(1)
        Else
            Debug.Print xChild.Text
        End If


    Next xChild

    'Output:
    'ABCe0552553
    'ABCe05525531
    '1
    'Cust1234
    'Smith
    'New York
    '101
    'MP3 Player
    '102
    'Radio


End Sub
```

And the following uses regex, which is really only useful if the XML is fixed to exactly your example each time. It's not really recommended for parsing XML in general unless you want speed over reliability.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RegexMethod()
Dim XMLString As String
Dim oRegex As Object
Dim regexArr As Object
Dim rItem As Object

    'Assumes Sheet1.Range("A1").Value holds example XMLString
    XMLString = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

    Set oRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With oRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(id=""|>)(.+?)(""|</)"
        Set regexArr = .Execute(XMLString)

        'No lookbehind so replace unwanted chars
        .Pattern = "(id=""|>|""|</)"
        For Each rItem In regexArr
            'Change Debug.Print to fill an array to write to Excel
            Debug.Print .Replace(rItem, vbNullString)
        Next rItem
    End With

    'Output:
    'ABCe0552553
    'ABCe05525531
    '1
    'Cust1234
    'Smith
    'New York
    '101
    'MP3 Player
    '102
    'Radio


End Sub
```

EDIT: Slight update to output to array for writing to range

```
Option Explicit

Sub RegexMethod()
Dim XMLString As String
Dim oRegex As Object
Dim regexArr As Object
Dim rItem As Object
Dim writeArray(1 To 1, 1 To 10) As Variant
Dim col As Long

    'Assumes Sheet1.Range("A1").Value holds example XMLString
    XMLString = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

    Set oRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With oRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(id=""|>)(.+?)(""|</)"
        Set regexArr = .Execute(XMLString)

        'No lookbehind so replace unwanted chars
        .Pattern = "(id=""|>|""|</)"
        For Each rItem In regexArr
            'Change Debug.Print to fill an array to write to Excel
            Debug.Print .Replace(rItem, vbNullString)

            col = col + 1
            writeArray(1, col) = .Replace(rItem, vbNullString)
        Next rItem
    End With

    Sheet1.Range("A5:J5").Value = writeArray


End Sub


Sub XMLMethod()
Dim XMLString As String
Dim XMLDoc As Object
Dim boolValue As Boolean
Dim xmlDocEl As Object
Dim xMeContext As Object
Dim xChild As Object
Dim xorder As Object
Dim writeArray(1 To 1, 1 To 10) As Variant
Dim col As Long


    XMLString = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

    'Remove xa: in this example
    'reason : "Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'xa'."
    'Shouldn't need to do this if full XML is well formed
    XMLString = Replace(XMLString, "xa:", vbNullString)

    Set XMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    'XMLDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xa:"

        'XMLDoc.Load = "C:\Users\ooo\Desktop\test.xml" 'load from file
    boolValue = XMLDoc.LoadXML(XMLString)  'load from string

    Set xmlDocEl = XMLDoc.DocumentElement
    Set xMeContext = xmlDocEl.SelectSingleNode("//MeContext")
        'Debug.Print Split(xMeContext.XML, """")(1)
        col = col + 1
        writeArray(1, col) = Split(xMeContext.XML, """")(1)
    For Each xChild In xmlDocEl.ChildNodes

        If xChild.NodeName = "Orders" Then
            For Each xorder In xChild.ChildNodes
                col = col + 1
                'Debug.Print Split(xorder.XML, """")(1)
                writeArray(1, col) = Split(xorder.XML, """")(1)
                col = col + 1
                'Debug.Print xorder.Text
                writeArray(1, col) = xorder.Text
            Next xorder
        ElseIf xChild.Text = "" Then
            col = col + 1
            'Debug.Print Split(xChild.XML, """")(1)
            writeArray(1, col) = Split(xChild.XML, """")(1)
        Else
            col = col + 1
            'debug.Print xChild.Text
            writeArray(1, col) = xChild.Text
        End If


    Next xChild

    Sheet1.Range("A5:J5").Value = writeArray


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write the two code examples.  You are displaying the output per XML record in vertical fashion (one Excel row per output).  Is it possible to have the output in horizontal fashion (displaying the output to columns rather than rows) ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a crude way to dump the data into an array for writing out to a sheet.